# Separate an array in others by comparing its numerical items in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am new to Javascript and I am trying to separate this array into several chuncks, each chunck must contain numbers whose difference between them is less than or equal to 10, for example from this array:

```
arr = [26,36,47,48,57, 87,97]
```

Has to be separated into three:

```
arr1 = [26,36]
arr2 = [47,48,57]
arr3 = [87,97]
```

If someone could help, thank you.

Comment: You should show us what you tried. StackOverflow is meant for helping, not for doing it for you.

Comment: How to split this array: `[26, 36, 40, 47, 48, 57, 87, 97]`? (notice the additional `40`).

Comment: This array [26, 36, 40, 47, 48, 57, 87, 97] most be separate in [26,36,40,47,48,57] and [87,97] , the diference betwen its numbers is less than 10.

Comment: @user9034707 is the array laways sorted (in ascending order)?

Comment: Iam traying to separate an array comparing its items, this is just an example, it could be by diference between it items of 2, or whatever.

Comment: Yes, always sorted in ascending order.

Comment: Where is you code? You need to attempt it and show us what you have tried.This isn't DoMyHomeworkForMe.com

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array#reduce` to accumulate result in an array and the another key to keep track of of values to compare with the last values whose difference is less than 10.

```js
arr = [26,36,47,48,57, 87,97];
var result = arr.reduce((r, v, i) => {
  if(i && v - r.num <= 10)
    r.arr[r.arr.length - 1].push(v)
  else {
    r.num = v;
    r.arr.push([v]);
  }
  return r;
},{num:0,arr:[]});
console.log(result.arr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check the predecessor and use either a new sub array or the last array for pushing.

This proposal works for sorted arraya.

```js
var array = [26, 36, 47, 48, 57, 87, 97],
    result = array.reduce(function (r, a, i, aa) {
        if (aa[i - 1] + 10 >= a) {
            r[r.length - 1].push(a);
        } else {
            r.push([a]);
        }
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the array and for each element check if the difference from the last element is less than or equal 10, if so then push the current element into the same group, if not then create a new group and so the same for the rest of the elements:

```js
function separate(arr) {
  var last = arr[0],                               // the last item (to check against) is the first one
      group = [last],                              // the current group (which initially contains the first item of the array)
      groups = [group];                            // the array that contains all the groups (initially containing the current group)
      
  for(var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {            // from the second item of the array
      if(arr[i] - last <= 10) {                    // if the diff between the current item and the last one is <= than 10
          group.push(arr[i]);                      // then push the current item into the current group
      } else {                                     // otherwise
          group = [arr[i]];                        // create a new group that initially contains the current item (and make it the current group by assigning it to the variable group)
          groups.push(group);                      // push the group into the groups array
      }
      last = arr[i];                               // assign the current item to last
  }
  
  return groups;
}

console.log(separate([26, 36, 47, 48, 57, 87, 97]));
```

Which can be done using `reduce` in a consize way like:

```js
function separate(arr) {
  return arr.slice(1).reduce(function(groups, el) {
      var group = groups[groups.length - 1];
      if(el - group[group.length - 1] <= 10) {
          group.push(el);
      } else {
          groups.push([el]);
      }
      return groups;
  }, [[arr[0]]]);
}

console.log(separate([26, 36, 47, 48, 57, 87, 97]));
```